# Ajuda com DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS - Oracle para DB2

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, db2

Estou passando uma procedure de Oracle para DB2 e não estou conseguindo rodar por conta do DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS :

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('DMTLDBR','TB_FATO_OBJETIVO',PART_MES_ANT,10, TRUE,'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE REPEAT',4,'ALL',TRUE,null,null,null,FALSE);
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('DMTLDBR','TB_FATO_AGR_SEMAN_DATAEXT_CUST',PART_MES_ANT,10, TRUE,'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE REPEAT',4,'ALL',TRUE,null,null,null,FALSE);
```

O que eu devo trocar para que a procedure rode, estou com erro no DBMS;

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

`DBMS_STATS` é um pacote de comandos do `oracle` que não existe no `db/2`.

Na sua query, está usando `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS`, que o objetivo é otimizar a query com as estatísticas, então em princípio deveria remover isso, os *hints* de performance de um banco não são os mesmo em outro banco, não deve funcionar da mesma maneira porque os bancos se comportam de maneira diferente em relação a performance como índices e planos de execução (seria o mesmo com `index(..)`).

De qualquer forma, o comando mais próximo no `db/2` é o [`RUNSTATS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001980.html)

Comment: Ricardo,
Obrigado pela ajuda.
Quando eu coloco ``RUNSTATS`` no DB2 ele não reconhece.
Sabe como ficaria a sintaxe ``DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('DMTLDBR','TB_FATO_OBJETIVO',PART_MES_ANT,10, TRUE,'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE REPEAT',4,'ALL',TRUE,null,null,null,FALSE);`` com o ``RUNSTATS``?
Estou procurando tutoriais mas eu não consigo achar nada.

Comment: não conheço bem db2 nem o `RUNSTATS` para te ajudar, teria que ler a documentação e fazer testes, mas como falei, primeiro deveria executar a query sem nenhum hint/aprimoramento, testar, ver se a performance está boa e talvez nem precise, se precisar ai sim analisar o plano de execução e experimetar as possíveis opções que deixem a query com melhor performance.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo!!!